# Visual Basic - Cannot access file because used by another process even after closed file

Tags: vb.net, file, process, streamwriter

My script automatically uploads a text file after being created and editted through the program. The creating and editting (appending) works fine, but when the exe reaches the line where the file is uploaded, I get the error:

> Cannot access file because used by another process

The file is being closed and disposed before uploading, but that doesn't matter. Even after some google searches I can't find the problem and solution.

I use the following code to create and append the text.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAdd.Click
    Try
        Using file As New System.IO.StreamWriter(currentdir + "\logs\" + FormClient.gametitle + "." + FormLogin.username + "_" + thisDate + "_ [" + fileNumber + "]" + ".txt", True)
            file.WriteLine(TxtIssue.Text + "      " + TxtWhen.Text + "      " + TxtWhere.Text + "      " + TxtInfo.Text)
            file.WriteLine("")
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(("Error while loading: " + ex.Message))
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub FormFeedback_Closing(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    thisDate = Today
    Dim filenameFormat = currentdir + "\logs\" + FormClient.gametitle + "." + FormLogin.username + "_" + thisDate + "_ [" + fileNumber + "]" + ".txt"
    Dim uploadFormat = Path.Combine("-removed-", filenameFormat)
    My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(filenameFormat, uploadFormat, "mennovv", "mennomail98", True, 500)

End Sub
```

The following piece of code checks if a file exists, but I don't think this is the problem.

```
While My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(currentdir + "\logs\" + FormClient.gametitle + "." + FormLogin.username + "_" + thisDate + "_ [" + fileNumber + "]" + ".txt") = True
        fileNumber += 1
    End While
```

Comment: Did you close() the streamWriter after writing a file ?

Comment: Yes I did. It doesn't help anything.

Comment: Little reason to assume it isn't accurate.  You did not help us help you by obfuscating with "-removed-".  Keep in mind that the process might be running on another machine and that your FileExists() check won't work when more than one program is doing this.

Comment: Update the question after close() method. Because close() method is very imp for this problem.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with updating the question?

@Hans Passant The -removed- shows a link to my FTP server, it has nothing to do with the file itself. The FileExists() part of the code is actually initiated before writing/opening the file, so no problems with that.

Comment: An FTP server doesn't generate this exception so it must be the local copy of the file.  You are missing something, we can't see it either.  Convince yourself with the SysInternals' Handle utility.

Comment: What's strange about the sample code above is that you appear to be instantiating the "file" object in your Button1_Click method, but you don't close it in the same method.  Are you declaring this variable elsewhere, or is it simply locally-scoped?

Comment: The variable is declared and closed within the same method now after I did some editting. Still doesn't work, sadly.